# Replicating Array.reduce() method

Tags: swift, closures, higher-order-functions

I am trying to replicate the `Array.reduce()` method in my custom class and realised that it uses Result as type. Just could not understand that is the Result type been created as Enum or is it something else.

```
import Foundation

public class MyArray {
    private var arr: [Int] = []
    internal static var instance: MyArray?

    private init() {}

    public static func getInstance() -> MyArray {
        if self.instance == nil {
            self.instance = MyArray()
        }
        return self.instance!
    }

    public func insert(value val: Int) {
        arr.append(val)
    }

    /*************** Custom reduce like function ***************/

    public func perform(_ initialResult: Int, _ nextPartialResult: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
        var result = initialResult

        for element in arr {
            result = nextPartialResult(result, element)  // calling the closure
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Now accessing the MyArray class from outside

```
var arr1 = MyArray.getInstance()
arr1.insert(value: 1)
arr1.insert(value: 2)
arr1.insert(value: 4)
arr1.insert(value: 3)
arr1.insert(value: 2)
arr1.insert(value: 5)
arr1.insert(value: 2)
arr1.insert(value: 2)

//  :Complex calculations left for user to implement
var result = arr1.perform(0) {
    return $0 + ( $1 * $1)
}
print("Complex calculation in elements of MEMBER array of arr1: \(result)")

//  :Just another way of writing the above closure
result = arr1.perform(0) { (result, num1) -> Int in
    return result + ( num1 * num1)
}
print("Complex calculation in elements of MEMBER array of hello arr1: \(result)")

//  :Simple calculations
print("Factorial of elements in MEMBER array of arr1: \(arr1.perform(1, *))")
print("Sum of elements in MEMBER array of arr1: \(arr1.perform(0, +))")
```

The problem is that I have to define my perform() function with one particular type at a time ( Int or String or Double etc ). I am trying to create my function to work with any type just like the reduce() function.

I am not able to understand how to define the Result type in my class and then use it in my function !!

I understand that Result type is not a part of standard library in swift.

Comment: Unrelated but the `getInstance()` method is *objective-c-ish* and pointless. Just write `static let instance = MyArray()`  (call it `MyArray.instance`) and delete the entire `getInstance()` method. `static` variables are created lazily in Swift by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `reduce` function makes use of generics. See the [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) chapter in the Swift book.

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

It has two generic types: `Result` and `Element`. `Element` comes from the type of the values in the collection and `Result` comes from the result type of the reduced value.

So your first step is to use the identical signature in your own `perform` function.

But in doing so you will discover that you now need to make your `MyArray` class also based on a generic instead of being hardcoded to work only with `Int`.

And in attempting to do that you will discover that you can't define `MyArray` to be generic and support the singleton pattern at the same time. So you need to remove `instance` and `getIntance()`.

The end result becomes:

```
public class MyArray<Element> {
    private var arr: [Element] = []

    public init() {}

    public func insert(value val: Element) {
        arr.append(val)
    }

    /*************** Custom reduce like function ***************/

    public func perform<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) -> Result) -> Result {
        var result = initialResult

        for element in arr {
            result = nextPartialResult(result, element)
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

With this in place, your first example becomes:

```
var arr1 = MyArray<Int>()
arr1.insert(value: 1)
arr1.insert(value: 2)
arr1.insert(value: 4)
arr1.insert(value: 3)
arr1.insert(value: 2)
arr1.insert(value: 5)
arr1.insert(value: 2)
arr1.insert(value: 2)

//  :Complex calculations left for user to implement
var result = arr1.perform(0) {
    return $0 + ( $1 * $1)
}
print(result)
```

And this outputs the desired result of `67`.

In the end, it works but if you'll notice, there's no point to this `MyArray` class (other than a learning exercise). Just use `Array`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rmaddy. This is exactly I was looking for. But what I am not able to understand is that is the Result type already defined in the standard library or do we have to define it somewhere in our code??

Comment: `Result` is an arbitrary name used for the generic. I could have used `Etwwc` (any random identifier). Please read the Generics chapter I linked to understand.

Comment: Dear @rmaddy, thanks a lot for the valuable advise. I am going through the Generics chapter right now and it seems to be very interesting. At the moment I am learning

Comment: Dear @rmaddy, thanks a lot for the valuable advise. I am going through the Generics chapter right now and it seems to be very interesting. At the moment I am learning Type Constraints. But I need help with my MyArray class. I have provided a link below to my custom class. Can you please download and see why am I getting these errors after implementing "Element" as advised by you. Honestly I am not able to make out how to correct these errors. Your help will be highly appreciated. [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hwymf97bih65cgi/AABxlxxyrPqH48l9oVsvnI4la?dl=0].

Comment: @vermau If you have a new question with new issues, please post a new question.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, sure I will take care of that in the future. Just out of excitement, I was able to solve the errors in MyArray class and now my code is running fine with generics. Once again thanks a lot for your help